# Chocolatey Install Package Failing

Tags: powershell, cmd, arm, chocolatey

For those who are familiar with creating Chocolatey packages, can someone offer help to why this one isn't working? It packs, but when I test (install only package), it won't work.
Here is the `chocolateyinstall.ps1` file:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; # stop on all errors
$toolsDir   = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
$fileLocation = Join-Path $toolsDir 'armcc.exe'
$packagename = 'ARM_RVCT'

$packageArgs = @{
  packageName   = $packageName
  unzipLocation = $toolsDir
  fileType      = 'EXE' #only one of these: exe, msi, msu
  #url           = $url
  #url64bit      = $url64
  file         = $fileLocation

  softwareName  = 'ARM_RVCT*' #part or all of the Display Name as you see it in Programs and Features. It should be enough to be unique

  silentArgs    = '/S' # ALLUSERS=1 DISABLEDESKTOPSHORTCUT=1 ADDDESKTOPICON=0 ADDSTARTMENU=0
  validExitCodes= @(0)
}

Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage @packageArgs # https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-install-package
```

When I do `choco pack` and then run `choco install arm_rvct`, I get this output:

```
Installing the following packages:
arm_rvct
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.

arm_rvct v3.1
arm_rvct package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Installing ARM_RVCT...
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
Error: C3079E: armcc command with no effect
Error: C3065E: type of input file '/S' unknown
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
ERROR: Running ["C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\arm_rvct\tools\armcc.exe" /S ] was not successful. Exit code was '1'. See log for possible error messages.
The install of arm_rvct was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\arm_rvct\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - arm_rvct (exited 1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\arm_rvct\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you exactly what the problem is in the error message:

```
Error: C3079E: armcc command with no effect
Error: C3065E: type of input file '/S' unknown
```

First, it looks like you might be commenting out, or at the very least, not providing required parameters for `armcc.exe`. Second, it looks like `/S` in the context of `armcc.exe` isn't for a silent install - it wants an input file which you are not currently providing as part of your silent args.

---

`armcc.exe` isn't an installer btw - if you don't have a proper installer for your toolchain, consider putting the toolchain in a zip archive, embedding that zip in your package, and then install with [`Install-ChocolateyZipPackage`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-zip-package) instead of [`Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-install-package) (the latter is for installing exe or msi installers).

This should automatically generate some shims for your executables and place them on the path. Note that since this looks like it's for the `arm_rvct` compiler, if that normally accepts pipeline input, Chocolatey shims actually do not support pipeline input, so keep that limitation with generated shims in mind.

---

It does look like there is an [official installer](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/arm-compiler/downloads/version-6) for the ARM toolchain. However, the [installation instructions](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/arm-compiler/downloads/version-6) in the release notes don't provide any silent install instructions. That said, this is a common problem with undocumented installers - but it doesn't mean that you can't perform a silent install either, with some effort on your side.

You can either try running `setup.exe /S` or the referenced `ARM Compiler 6.13.msi` with `msiexec /i "ARM Compiler 6.13.msi" /qn`. If neither of these work, you have the options of reaching out to the vendor to ask how silent installs work, or you can go the route of taking the installed files and packaging them into a zip. Note that installers, especially for devkits and toolchains, may register assemblies in Windows and this can get complicated to reverse engineer if a simple file install doesn't work.

---

In this case though, the vendor would be the best resource to understand how you are able to deploy this package throughout your organization.

Comment: I cannot find the correct silent install switch for armcc.exe, and I would use the vendor but the problem is that I need very specific versions for this, and all other software I package, many of which is outdated. The only place I have the software is locally. Is it failing because I am using the actual software.exe and do I need to use the installer.exe instead? Also, how would I know what parameters are needed.  Sorry, I am the only person here working with Chocolatey and have no experience with any of it. Just trying to learn and succeed.

Comment: Yes, it is failing because you are trying to run `armcc.exe` like an installer, but `armcc` is the ARM compiler. In other words, it gets installed by the installer, it is not itself the installer. With Chocolatey, you *usually* create packages that do one of two things - run a [setup installer](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-install-package) (could be an EXE or MSI) or you [zip the files inside the package and "install" the zip](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-zip-package).

Comment: To your point, "I need very specific versions for this, and all other software I package, many of which is outdated", somebody in your organization should be able to tell you where to find the installers. Someone installs this software manually today, right? They should be able to give you or tell you where to get the sources.